# Can´t get the unsigned long value of a NSNumber

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to get the unsigned long value of a NSNumber. I don´t know why, but it doesn't work. Here is what I did:

```
NSString * stern = [idd objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // get a String with Number from a NSArray
NSNumberFormatter * lols = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
NSNumber * iddd = [lols numberFromString:stern];
NSLog(@"%@", iddd); // I get the right number: 8084143463
unsigned long fooo = [iddd unsignedLongValue];
NSLog(@"%lu", fooo); // I get the wrong number: 3789176167
[twitterEngine deleteUpdate:fooo];
```

Comment: What do the values look like in the debugger? Are they the same as what is printed?

Comment: For what it's worth, on 10.6.2, I get 8084143463 both times, and the debugger values are consistent. I'd suggest replacing your first line with `NSString * stern = @"8084143463";` and renaming the variables to make sense to the casual observer.

Comment: Yes, the NSNumber is 8084143463 and the unsigned long 3789176167

Comment: Strange, I tried numberFromString:@"12345" and then fooo gets the right value. But I want the number from the stern-string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
8084143463 == 0x1e1da3d67
3789176167 == 0x0e1da3d67
```

The size of a long on a 64bit system is 8 bytes.  The size of a long on a 32bit system (like the iPhone) is 4 bytes.  You need to use a `long long` on an iPhone to store that value.

Comment: That sounds logisch, thanks for the answer. But I tried it with long long fooo = [iddd longLongValue]; and foo is again 3789176167

Answer (score 3):

Your value is larger than the maximum value an unsigned long can hold (2^32 - 1 == 4,294,967,295) in 32-bit mode.